# Unreal past with the modal verb 'could'

Tags: grammar, past-tense, modal-verbs

Can I use the modal verb 'could' in the if-clause?

For example:

> If he could have studied last year, he could have been a university student.

The first 'could' represents the ability and the second one represents the possibility.  Is this sentence possible?

Or should it be like this?

> If he had been able to study last year, he could have been a university student.

Comment: The second 'could' should be 'would'. You already stated what *could* have happened, and that was the result.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's a fine distinction, but I don't think you can say that the meaning of the second ***could*** is somehow "implied" by the first one. If he had (in the past) ***been able*** to study, ***it is possible*** he would be (or ***have been***, it's ambiguous) a university student. Switching that second ***could*** to ***would*** effectively asserts that he would *definitely* become a uni student later (if he'd studied), which isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not so fine, I think. The first sentence using two *could*s would be better as "He could have studied last year; he could have been a university student." The second could isn't the follow-on from the first conditional, but a restatement of the same thing. Or "If he could have studied last year, ***if*** he could have been a university student..."

Comment: The format *"He could have studied last year; he could have been a university student"* kinda muddies the issue for me, 'cos it sits somewhere between *He could have studied last year **in which case he would have been** a university student* and *He could have studied last year **in which case it might have been possible** for him to become a university student*. But the most obvious real-world connections between the referents here mean there's not much *semantic* difference however it's phrased. The likelihoods of all the hypotheticals are inherently tied together, like an accumulator bet.